# Fresh Valet install not pinging .test

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, dnsmasq, laravel-valet

I'm trying to get Valet running on a new MacBook Pro running macOS 12.3. Homebrew, PHP, and Composer are all installed just fine and functioning (to the extent of my knowledge).

However, once I installed Valet and tried to `ping foobar.test` it's not returning `127.0.0.1` (it's some `198.#.#.#` IP) and I cannot access it in my browser either. I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET message.

If I go to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` directly in my browser, I get the "404 - Not Found" Valet message I'd expect.

Running `brew services list`, I get the following:

```
Name    Status     User File
dnsmasq error  512 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mariadb started    root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
nginx   error  256 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php     started    root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
unbound error  256 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.unbound.plist
```

The "error" statuses seem suspect, but I've been battling those for years on previous machines where Valet *does* work.

I've tried restarting my MacBook, restarting Valet (also as `sudo`), and removing/reinstalling Valet. Nothing seems to help.

Not sure what to try since nothing resulted in errors during installation. All community posts seem to point to reinstalling Valet, which as mentioned, doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalled FortiClient and the issue went away. See if you have any VPN client or installed.

Comment: I did have FortiClient installed and removed it and reinstalled Valet, but the issue persisted. I'm going to see if I can find more old config files to remove and try to reinstall again.

Comment: Check `/etc/resolver/`

Answer (score 2):

I previously had this issue and found out the root cause for those with FortiClient was it was enabling the `pf` firewall in OSX and having a NAT DNS Redirect.

To verify what I was seeing running `sudo pfctl -s nat` gave me a line containing:
`rdr pass inet proto udp from any to any port = 53 -> 127.0.0.1 port 53535`

If you require having FortiClient and also to use valet in local development there has been a couple of workaround found:

- resetting `pf`'s configuration
- editing /etc/hosts to add the hosts statically (though this doesn't scale if many, changing hosts)

To reset PF I would do the following:

```bash
# reset the rules based off the on-disk version
sudo pfctl -N -f /etc/pf.conf

# clear the DNS cache on system
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

After checking the NAT rules in `pf` I then get the default response of:

```
$ sudo pfctl -s nat
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
nat-anchor “com.apple/*” all
rdr-anchor “com.apple/*” all
```

NOTE: Resetting pf's config might have some other side-effects as part of it, though from my experience using it for the past month, it seems to work without any issues for my setup